# How to append constant value to SAPUI5 table column value

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to append constant "1:" to one of the table column values.
My table column is :

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
    selectionMode : sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single,
    selectionBehavior: sap.ui.table.SelectionBehavior.Row
 });
    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({

        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Rate"}),

        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value: "{RATE}"})

      }));
```

Now on that above column **i am trying to add constant as "1:"**. But if i try like as shown below, i don't get the desired result.

```
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({

            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Rate"}),

            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value: "1:"+"{RATE}"})

          }));
```

I intend to do this change in a clean way if possible?
How can i achieve this?
Looking forward to your solutions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your solution work? Can you try new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value: "1:{RATE}"}); ?

Comment: No It doesn't work when i try the above solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution it will work.

```
template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
    value: { 
       path: 'RATE', //Binding Context field here
       formatter: function(value){
         return '1: ' + value;
       } 
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anil. Yes it worked perfectly. Thanks a lott